# Making height of 3D Plot more clear from top view

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I'm plotting a 3d function and looking at it from above. here is the function definition:

```
lagz[n_, m_, z_, zbar_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*n!*m!]* E^(z*zbar/(2.*a^4)) * (a)^(m + n)*
   D[ E^(-(z*zbar)/a^4), {z, n}, {zbar, m}] /. {a -> 1}
lagnlz[n_, l_, z_, zbar_] := 
 Sqrt[n!/(Pi*a^2*(n + l)!)]* (z/a)^l LaguerreL[n, l, z*zbar/a^2]*
   E^(-z*zbar/(2.*a^2)) /. {a -> 1}
lag[n_, l_, r_, \[Theta]_] := 
 lagnlz[n, l, z, zbar] /. {z -> r*E^(I*\[Theta]), 
   zbar -> r*E^(-I*\[Theta])}
lagcc[n_, l_, r_, \[Theta]_] := 
 lagnlz[n, l, z, zbar] /. {z -> r*E^(-I*\[Theta]), 
   zbar -> r*E^(I*\[Theta])}
```

And here is the code I'm using to plot:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 lag[1, 1, r, \[Theta]]*lagcc[1, 1, r, \[Theta]], {r, 0, 
  3}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> Above]
```

From the "Above" view, it is not at all clear (at least to me) that the height of the inner ring is larger than the height of the outer ring. Is there some setting or coloring I can use that will make the height difference much more apparent from this "Above" view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Don't use machine numbers in the function definitions

```
lagz[n_, m_, z_, zbar_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*n!*m!]*E^(z*zbar/(2*a^4))*(a)^(m + n)*
   D[E^(-(z*zbar)/a^4), {z, n}, {zbar, m}] /. {a -> 1}
lagnlz[n_, l_, z_, zbar_] := 
 Sqrt[n!/(Pi*a^2*(n + l)!)]*(z/a)^l LaguerreL[n, l, z*zbar/a^2]*
   E^(-z*zbar/(2*a^2)) /. {a -> 1}
lag[n_, l_, r_, θ_] := 
 lagnlz[n, l, z, zbar] /. {z -> r*E^(I*θ), zbar -> r*E^(-I*θ)}
lagcc[n_, l_, r_, θ_] := 
 lagnlz[n, l, z, zbar] /. {z -> r*E^(-I*θ), zbar -> r*E^(I*θ)}

min = MinValue[{lag[1, 1, r, θ]*lagcc[1, 1, r, θ], 0 <= r <= 3, 
   0 <= θ <= 2 Pi}, {r, θ}]

(* 0 *)

max = MaxValue[{lag[1, 1, r, θ]*lagcc[1, 1, r, θ], 0 <= r <= 3, 
    0 <= θ <= 2 Pi}, {r, θ}] // Simplify

(* ((31 - 7 Sqrt[17]) E^(1/2 (-5 + Sqrt[17])))/(4 π) *)

max // N

(* 0.109758 *)

RevolutionPlot3D[
 lag[1, 1, r, θ]*lagcc[1, 1, r, θ], {r, 0, 3}, {θ, 0, 
  2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> Above, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why do you suggest not using machine numbers in the function definition?

Comment: Using machine numbers introduces numerical errors that keep `MaxValue` from getting an accurate maximum.